# How to export post meta with images in wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, images, import, export

Hi i have a custom post type in my two websites and i have to to export all posts in that post type and import to second site .

So my post type is **"products"** . Actually i can use wordpress default import export but the problem is that it is not including the full details in the post type and not exporting all imges.

In my product i have a additional image galley section near featured image side bar . Here i can add gallery images .

so if my **post id is 324** and i **added two galley images** for that post then in database post_meta_option i can see that

**post_id=324**, ***meta_key=rtthemert_gallery_images*** ,**meta_value =222,223**  here 223,224 are image id .

So please anyone can help to make an export query for this gallery images only . So that when i import to second site the gallery images also need to automatically added to that post .